# Dynamic Data to external database asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-dynamic-data

I'm stepping through a [walk through](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee923692(v=vs.100).aspx#adding_the_data_model_to_the_web_application) which allows me to create a dynamic data website.

Though in all the tutorials, including the one above, they all point to a local file based database. I need to add an external data model.

**How could I add an external data model to the project?** (A database hosted on a seperate SQL Server)

I've tried connecting through the SQL Server Object Explorer then dragging it into App_Data, but that didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Look up how to use a seperate connection string in your WebConfig.

Comment: @durbnpoisn I have a seperate connection string in my web.config. What now?

Comment: Uh...  Assuming your security is set properly on the server to allow remote connections, you should be able to work with the DB the same as the local.  Are you getting any sorts of errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use the connection string in the web.config, but as you add the EF data model you should be given the opportunity to select you database by browsing for it.